# Snowflake auth issues using AWS SageMaker notebooks

Tags: python, authentication, jupyter-notebook, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-sagemaker

We're using Python 3.x locally to connect to Snowflake, using the "externalbrowser" authentication method. This works quite nicely running code locally, where it automatically opens another browser tab and finishes authenticating that way.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL

engine = create_engine(URL(
account="MY_ACCOUNT",
user="MY_USERNAME",
authenticator="externalbrowser",
role="MY_ROLE",
warehouse="MY_WAREHOUSE"
))
connection = engine.connect()
```

However running the same code from within an AWS SageMaker (Juypter) notebooks throws an error since it has no browser tab to open to complete the authentication. The error being returned is,

```
DatabaseError: (snowflake.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 250008 (08001): Failed to connect to DB: <MY_ACCOUNT>.snowflakecomputing.com:443, Unable to open a browser in this environment.
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)
```

We don't have any Okta authentication enabled or any other SAML (or OAuth) authentication options we can use instead. Is there any other way around this issue with SageMaker notebooks and externalbrowser authentication?

Answer (score 1):

SSO wont work from sagemaker notebooks with externalbrowser option. Instead of this, you may use one of the following options for authentication:

1. Username/Password - store the creds in secrets manager or ssm
2. Key pair auth - Assign the user the public key and use that to authenticate.
3. Run a local jupyter notebook but use boto3 to manage AWS assets (less secure depending on the environment setup)
4. External OAuth - Closest to being a pure SSO solution.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays (`snowflake-connector-python-3.0.4`), it will work, although the user experience it's not the best since you have to copy and paste very long url twice.

```
!pip install -U pip
!pip install 'snowflake-connector-python' # do NOT use 'snowflake-connector-python[secure-local-storage]'

import snowflake.connector

conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
    account="xxx",
    user="xxx",
    authenticator="externalbrowser",
    database="xxx",
    schema="xxx",
    warehouse="xxx",
)
cur = conn.cursor(snowflake.connector.DictCursor)
cur.execute('SELECT CURRENT_VERSION()').fetchone() # {'CURRENT_VERSION()': '7.19.2'}
```

on the `connect(...)` you will be prompted with

```
Initiating login request with your identity provider. A browser window should have opened for you to complete the login. If you can't see it, check existing browser windows, or your OS settings. Press CTRL+C to abort and try again...
Going to open: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/saml2?SAMLRequest=xxxx&RelayState=xxx to authenticate...
We were unable to open a browser window for you, please open the url above manually then paste the URL you are redirected to into the terminal.
Enter the URL the SSO URL redirected you to:  ________
```

If you actually do what the prompt tells you and **open that url manually**
by copy & paste that URL onto your browser, you will initiate the login process, and at the last step you will be redirected to `http://localhost:xxxxx/?token=xxxxx` and that will be **an error page** since there is nothing listening on that port on that machine (the processing listening on that port is actually on the sagemaker kernel).

But you should not pay attention to the error page (`This site can't be reached ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`). If you copy that final URL back into SageMaker into the box where it says `Enter the URL the SSO URL redirected you to:  ________`, the snowflake-connector-python will extract the token from that URL and use it to connect successfully.